# Subset-type function construction

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

This is probably a very straightforward thing I am missing, and probably also a duplicate(!), but I can't for the life of me think how to do this cleaner. I want to achieve what `bb[n]` does:

```
aa[list1_, list2_] := Select[Subsets[list1], 
Length@Complement[#, Complement[list1, list2]] == Length@list2 &]
bb[a_] := With[{c = x[#] & /@ Range@Length@a}, 
aa[c, #] & /@ Subsets[c] /. Thread[c -> a]]
```

*eg*

**in:** `bb[{1,2,3}]`

**out:**

```
{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 2, 3}}
```

Please could someone suggest a simpler, cleaner, more succinct way of achieving the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** for speed

It was slightly slower then `bb` in the OP so I tweaked it a bit.  It used to use

```
Function[{x}, Select[SubsetQ[#, x] &]@s] /@ s
```

but the new `Function` in `g` below, although bigger, completes in $\frac{4}{5}$ the time than `bb`. Now, on my machine:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[g[Range[11]];]
(* 17.6471 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[bb[Range[11]];]
(* 22.4707 *)
```

[image]

**Update** for duplicates

Using `Subsets` on the position vector of the list and then extracting from the list position subset as the `Part` spec.

```
g[t_List] :=
 With[{s = Subsets[Range@Length@t]},
  Map[
   t[[#]] &,
   Function[{x}, 
    Insert[x, 1]@Select[SubsetQ[#, x] &]@Select[Length@# > Length@x &]@s] /@ s,
   {2}]
  ]


g[{1, 2, 3}]

(*
{
 {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{1, 2, 3}}
}
*)
```

Works with duplicates.

```
g[{1, 1, 2}]

(*
{
 {{}, {1}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, 
 {{1, 1, 2}}
}
*)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: another nice approach, thanks - will still need that fix for duplicates though - see SimonWoods' 1st and second edit (try `g@{1,1,2}`)

Comment: @martin Updated for duplicates.  It basically `Map`s `Part` into the result of the `Function` in the original post with `Subsets` of the position vector of the list instead of the list itself.

Comment: @martin Updated for speed.

Comment: nice improvements :)

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
f = With[{s = Subsets[#], r = Subsets[Range@Length@#]},
 Pick[s, #] & /@ Outer[SubsetQ[#2, #1] &, r, r, 1]] &

f[{1, 1, 2}] // Column

(* 
{{},{1},{1},{2},{1,1},{1,2},{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{1},{1,1},{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{1},{1,1},{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{1,1},{1,1,2}}
{{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{1,2},{1,1,2}}
{{1,1,2}}
*)
```

Comment: that's nice, but doesn't give same output as `bb` if duplicates - eg `bb@{1,1,2}`

Comment: Looks like we had similar ideas for a fix :-)

Comment: looks good now - much cleaner - thanks! :)

Comment: FYI in your original code `Flatten[{#[[1]] -> #[[2]]} & /@ Transpose@{c, a}]` can be written more succinctly as `Thread[a -> c]`

Comment: thanls - that is useful to know - will leave Q open for a bit as per MMA SE etiquette, but will no doubt accept shortly :)

Comment: Yes please leave it open for a day or so, this sort of question is usually very popular and it will be good to see alternative approaches.

Comment: agreed -will do :)